# awk print not printing complete line with linefeed or carrigae return

Tags: awk

In awk program, I read a text value with a few either linefeed or carriage-return in the text, I assigned it to a awk variable, say named str, I check the length of the _str and it has the right length, but when I try to print it using awk "print" but it only print the first part of the before the first linefeed o carriage return and discard the rest of the characters, any idea why?  And how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Show us the awk script, show us your output, and show us what you expected.  It's very difficult to debug code that we can't see.

Comment: It is reading from a file, let me show what is relevant here :

Comment: Oops..  accidentally closed previous comments, continue here...I read from a file content,  the awk command is "k=length(_str)  print str", that's it.  I suspected it was not the linefeed, I hexdump the file but there is no non-printable characters"  I even do a replace or all non-printable characters, "\001-\007\013\016-\037" but I still seeing half of the string content but the length is showing longer than what got printed out.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your `few either linefeed or carriage-return` are causing overwriting/backspacing/mayhem in your output. Run `dos2unix` or similar on the file first and then try again. If that doesn't solve your problem, update your question as @ghoti suggested.